# Java Aes class convert to php

Tags: java, php, encryption

Java code :

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESSecurityUtil {

    private static final String AES = "AES";  
    private static final String CHARSET_NAME = "utf-8";  


    private static SecretKeySpec getKey(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{  

        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(AES);  
        SecureRandom random=SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        random.setSeed(password.getBytes());
        kgen.init(128, random);    

        SecretKey secretKey = kgen.generateKey();  
        byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();    
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat, AES);   
        return key;  
    }  


    public static String encode(String str, String password)  
    {  
        byte[] arr = encodeToArr(str, password);  
        return byteArrToString(arr);  
    }  


    private static byte[] encodeToArr(String str, String password)  
    {  
        try
        {  
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES);
            byte[] byteContent = str.getBytes(CHARSET_NAME);  

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getKey(password));
            byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(byteContent);    
            return result;  
        }  
        catch (Exception e)  
        {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }    
        return null;  
    }  


    public static String decode(String hexStr, String password){  
        byte[] arr = string2ByteArr(hexStr);  
        return decode(arr, password);  
    }  


    private static String decode(byte[] arr, String password)  {  
        try{  

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES);  
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getKey(password));

            byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(arr);  
            return new String(result, CHARSET_NAME);  
        }catch (Exception e){  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  



    private static String byteArrToString(byte[] arr)  {  
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();   
        for (int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++)  {    
            String s = Integer.toString(arr[i] + 128, 16);  
            if (s.length() == 1){  
                s = "0" + s;  
            }    
            sb.append(s);  
        }  

        return sb.toString().toUpperCase();  
    }  


    private static byte[] string2ByteArr(String s)  {  
        s = s.toUpperCase();  
        String str = "0123456789ABCDEF";    
        byte[] arr = new byte[s.length() / 2];   
        for (int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++){  
            char s1 = s.charAt(i * 2);  
            char s2 = s.charAt(i * 2 + 1);    
            int tmp1 = str.indexOf(s1) * 16;  
            int tmp2 = str.indexOf(s2);    
            arr[i] = (byte) (tmp1 + tmp2 - 128);  
        }    
        return arr;  
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
        System.out.println(decode("03AB8A3B85AFDD3926850B14C1BFF608", "imcc"));
        String keyStr = "UITN25LMUQC436IM";  

        String plainText = "this is a string will be AES_Encrypt";

        String encText = encode(plainText,keyStr);
        String decString = decode(encText,keyStr); 

        System.out.println(encText); 
        System.out.println(decString); 
    }
}
```

Does the class can turn into a php code to achieve encryption and decryption ? I think the problem is that the `getKey` method can not achieve in php.

This Java class, provided by the platform side, can not require making changes.

Please tell me where the problem is?

Thanks

Append ...my PHP code:

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('hex2bin')) {
    function hex2bin($str) {
        $sbin = "";
        $len = strlen($str);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += 2) {
            $sbin .= pack("H*", substr($str, $i, 2));
        }

        return $sbin;
    }
}

class Util_AesEncrypt {

    private $_cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
    private $_mode = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;

    private function _pkcs5Pad($text, $blockSize) {
        $pad = $blockSize - (strlen($text) % $blockSize);
        return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    }

    private function _pkcs5Unpad($text) {
        $end = substr($text, -1);
        $last = ord($end);
        $len = strlen($text) - $last;
        if (substr($text, $len) == str_repeat($end, $last)) {
            return substr($text, 0, $len);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function encrypt($encrypt, $key) {
        $blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size($this->_cipher, $this->_mode);
        $paddedData = $this->_pkcs5Pad($encrypt, $blockSize);
        $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->_cipher, $this->_mode);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt($this->_cipher, $key, $paddedData, $this->_mode, $iv);
        return bin2hex($encrypted);
    }

    public function decrypt($decrypt, $key) {
        $decoded = hex2bin($decrypt);
        $blockSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->_cipher, $this->_mode);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($blockSize, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt($this->_cipher, $key, $decoded, $this->_mode, $iv);
        return $this->_pkcs5Unpad($decrypted);
    }
}

$keyStr = 'UITN25LMUQC436IM';
$plainText = 'this is a string will be AES_Encrypt';
$aes = new Util_AesEncrypt();
$encText = $aes->encrypt($plainText, $keyStr);
$decString = $aes->decrypt($encText, $keyStr);

echo $encText, "\n", $decString;
```

Different encryption results

Comment: You need to understand requirements. php has it's own crypto capabilities, and of course you cannot just straightforwardly imitate java code. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @ArtjomB. php and Java get the same random values, this should not be able to do it?

Comment: I have missed that the password is used as a seed. In the case, you will have to implement SHA1PRNG in PHP. Even if you implement it correctly, this won't mean that you get the same key: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31500093

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thank you for helping, and I guess, like, T_T ...

Answer (score 1):

The JAVA `getKey()` function will get 128bit key from password use `SHA1PRNG`, you can use this PHP code to get key from password:

```
$key = substr(openssl_digest(openssl_digest($password, 'sha1', true), 'sha1', true), 0, 16);
```

I also spent a lot of time in this case, Good Luck.